# How to get/read NTP/SNMP configuration in Cisco ACI using API request?

Tags: cisco

I've been reading about Cisco APIC REST API User Guide - https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/aci/apic/sw/1-x/api/rest/b_APIC_RESTful_API_User_Guide/performing_common_tasks.html

and managed to get in using JSON API in Postman.

**Example (as documented in the link above):**

```
POST https://192.0.20.123/api/aaaLogin.json

{
"aaaUser":{
"attributes":{
"name":"georgewa",
"pwd":"paSSword1"
}
}
}
```

There are bunch of examples in the document on how to make changes on the ACI, but I couldn't find any examples to make a simple query without making any changes.

Let say how to get/read the current configuration in ACI, let say NTP or SNMP setting using API request?

Comment: Which tool are you using to send REST API? PostMan, curl .. etc

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **PostMan** to send REST API, first of all, you need to login into the APIC controller.

For example:

Method: **POST**
Body **raw**, Type **xml**:

```
https://IP_ADDRESS_APIC/api/mo/aaaLogin.xml

<aaaUser name='USERNAME' pwd='PASSWORD'/>
```

You will receive a token stored in a cookie which postman will store for you, It will last 5 minutes. After 5 minutes, you will need to log in again.

After that, you can run REST API.

For example:

Method: **GET**

```
https://IP_ADDRESS_APIC/api/class/datetimeNtpProvider.xml
```

In order to get all the NTP providers configured in the fabric.

If you prefer ***json*** format, then change REST URL to:

Method: **GET**

```
https://IP_ADDRESS_APIC/api/class/datetimeNtpProvider.json
```